# Exploded pie slice offset in pie chart using MSCHART

Tags: .net, winforms, mschart

I'm using pie chart from [MSCHART](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) library in WinForms application:

[image]

While exploding the slice representing any data point was simple (`point["Exploded"] = "true"`), manipulation of the gap size seems not to be such straightforward. Is there any way of setting how far the exploded part is offset (pulled away) from the pie ?

Comment: Hmm, no, not an option.